# How to Add Images to Infobox? - Bing Maps V8

Tags: bing-maps, pushpin

I would like to add images to my pushpin infoboxes but I am not sure how. I thought maybe htmlContent would do this but then the info box seems to be overwritten.

I really don't want to create a new popout just add images to the existing one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML and an img tag, then pass this in as the description value of the infobox. Here is a simple code sample:

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.60357, -122.32945)
});
var center = map.getCenter();
var infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(center, { title: 'Map Center',
    description: 'Here is my image: <img src="https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Content/images/poi_custom.png" />' });
infobox.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Yea, I found that I can add html to description box. Just took awhile with the size of the infobox since height/width do not work but maxWidth/maxHeight work.